Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 .Net Maui Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see... "
I am trying to use Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 nuget package on my .Net Maui project, to detect crop hints on a picture, unfortunatelly I am getting this error:
Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc

Here is my code:
Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromBytes(imageBytes);
ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
CropHintsAnnotation cropHints = client.DetectCropHints(image);
foreach (CropHint hint in cropHints.CropHints)
{
    string poly = string.Join(" - ", hint.BoundingPoly.Vertices.Select(v => $"({v.X}, {v.Y})"));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Crop hint:");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"  Poly: {poly}");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"  Confidence: {hint.Confidence}");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"  Importance fraction: {hint.ImportanceFraction}");
}

Following the instructions of the link I was able to generate a .json file
but I dont know how to make it work in .Net Maui, where to place or how to configure it.
How can I setup default Google Credentials in .Net Maui?

I'm unfamiliar with .NET MAUI but I'm familiar with Google Cloud. I think (!?) that you should not authenticate  using Application Default Credentials (ADC). IIUC the MAUI app runs client side and should authenticate as a (human) user (account). ADC and its use of Service Accounts is for server-side. My hunch (!?) is that you should refactor your app into client and server components and move the Google Cloud service functionality to this server.
